# Adding an image to woocommerce plain email footer

Tags: php, email, templates, woocommerce

How can I add an image to the woocommerce plain(not html) order-processing email? I am already modifying the template in my child theme anyways, so I am not looking for a function but oinstead adding the image directly to the customer-processing-order.php. I tried adding

```
    echo '<img src="'.home_url( "http://www.mysite/myimage.jpg" ).'" alt="myimage"/>';
```

just above the footer section in the template but the image is not being displayed.

Comment: As it's not displaying anything (not html but plain text), you can't add a displayed image to email footer for plain text emails.

Comment: d'oh...of course. thank you!